# What is the best way to store 'likes' in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, data-structures

The structure of my Firebase database is:

```
users: [
    {userId: {...}}, // Private data for specific user
    ...
],
likes: [ // Everybody has access to it
    goodsId: [111, 222, 333, 444] // Users' ids
]
```

Categories of goods and goods are stored on remote server, they are fetched by axios each time user navigates through catalog of goods or opens some goods card. I would like to store "likes" not on remote server but in Firebase. Is it correct or there is no need to do this? I don't know yet if I'll use realtime functionality for "likes", and whether I need this or not. Moreover, I suppose that each "like" request is request and my firebase quota will run out of limits sooner than usually. 
Will such structure allow me to quickly without performance issues to find  if the current user set "like" for every goods item he opens or searching array may cause performance problems (as you understand, there may be a big amount of users)?

Or maby this is a bad idea from the beginning to store "likes" in Firebase and I should only store there very specific data because I have quota limits - first, and second - I don't need real time functionality for each entity of my app. I need it only for those entities that I want to see in real time in admin part of reactjs web app: orders, chat, etc...

Comment: This is a highly subjective question. In general how you store data in Firebase is determined by what you want to get out. There's not problem storing likes and it could as simple as storing a list of uid: true in a child node. Firebase is 'live' so as someone adds a like, it would notify your app so you can update the UI. Again though there is no 'best' way, craft some sample code to try out a couple of options to see what works best for your use case.

Comment: @Jay that causes problems because then in terms of security rules anyone can write to your post, though it is the simplest way.

Comment: @Even It doesn't really cause any problems because rules can be added that controls who can or cannot write to your node in Firebase. My suggestion assumes the OP would put rules in to prevent random writes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could have this estructure:

```
{
    "users":
    {
        "id1":{}
    },
    "categories":{"cat1":{}}
    "likes":
    {
         "cat1"
         {
             "id1":true
         }
    }

}
```

That way you assure that one user can "like" something only once and in you db rules you could set reading permission to any auth user but writing permissions only for your auth id child in this case `id1` see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

And to checkout the like count, you could avoid getting all likes, having a "likeCount" field on your category child `cat1` having a Cloud Function that updates the like count every time a user likes some category, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_database_function

Also checkout this quick-start: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/database

Hope that helps! ;)

Comment: adding to this answer i would suggest using transactions in order to place likes in the database, since more than 1 user can post a like and if there are multiple users liking it might be a little concurrency problem posting the likes

Comment: Yes... Then... maby a good idea to store likes for each user personally?.. But how to count rating based on likes for each goods?..

Comment: @GastónSaillén Concurrency is not an issue. Firebase can handle multiple requests from multiple users easily and as long as the likes are stored sequentually - for example likes/uid_0: true and likes/uid_1: true it would not be an issue. This is assuming the OP wants to track who liked their post instead of just a count. Again though, the original question is unclear so suggesting a structure could be 100% wrong since we don't know the criteria.